# How to compare whether the coefficients of two independent variables statistically different from each other?

Tags: regression, self-study, statistical-significance, multiple-regression, stata

If I have two independent variables and they are dummy variable along with other independent variables and I run a linear probability model, I want to compare whether the coefficients of two dummy variables are statistically different from each other. I do not know how to compare that. Could someone help me on that?

Comment: Hint: think through the statistical procedure to determine statistical significance of coefficients. What is the coefficient estimate compared against?

Comment: what statistical procedure are you referring to do you mean the z statistic is coefficient divided by its standard error?

Comment: Sorry - that was a bit too elliptical. The test that you're looking for is the Wald test (http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92912/how-to-calculate-p-values-in-logistic-regression-with-gradient-descent-algorithm/92940). Usually, you compare the coefficient estimate to zero... But not in this case.

Comment: The Wald test seems to be used for one variable for it parameter and the proposed value at least based on wiki...but I have to compare two DIFFERENT dummy variables though...

Comment: When determining statistical significance of a single parameter, we compare whether it is sufficiently "far" from zero to reject the null that it is zero. But what is the null in this case, when you are comparing two coefficients to eachother?

Comment: there are two null in mind let say they are A and B...one scenario for null is A + B = 0. second scenario is A*B = 0... Are these the right approach?

Comment: An alternative to the answer you have is by [reparameterization of the model into parameter and difference of the two](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/93524/testing-whether-two-regression-coefficients-are-significantly-different-in-r-id), by suppling the basline dummy and the sum of the two dummies. and a direct test of the coefficient for the difference. (In fact given the fact that being a dummy makes no difference to the approach, this Q is arguably a duplicate.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I want to compare whether the coefficients of two dummy variables are statistically different from each other

I understand that you want to test the hypotheses $$H_0: A=B$$
$$H_1: A\not=B$$.

So we are performing inference on the quantity $A-B$ and evaluating whether it is sufficiently far from 0 relative to its standard error. Ordinarily, in the single-parameter case, we just compare, e.g., $A$ to its standard error. But we have two parameters here. So we have 
$$\sqrt{\frac{(A-B)^2}{\text{var}(A)+\text{var}(B)-2\text{cov}(A,B)}}$$ 
as our test statistic, where $\text{cov}(A,B)$ is the covaraince of $A$ and $B$. Now we compare the test statistic to a standard normal distribution.

Your last comment:

> there are two null in mind let say they are A and B...one scenario for null is A + B = 0. second scenario is A*B = 0... Are these the right appraoch?

confuses me, because it suggests that your null hypothesis is not that $H_0:A=B$, but instead that $H_0:A=-B$, or $H_0:A=1/B$. While not typical, this certainly might make sense for your particular research topic.

Comment: Based on what you said, I can set a null A - B = 0 and then use F test and If I can show that they are statistically significant ... it means they are statistically different from each other?

Comment: No, this is still a Wald test. But you have the general idea right: we are testing whether parameter $A$ is different from $B$.

Comment: what is the command for Wald test?

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not a STATA user.

Comment: The Stata command for a Wald test is `test`. The last hypothesis $H_0 : A = 1/B$ is a non-linear Wald test, the Stata command for that is `testnl`.

Comment: Quick question: Shouldn't the variance in the denominator for $H_0: A=B$ be $V(A) + V(B) - 2\cdot \text{Cov}(A,B)$? That is the variance of the difference of two random variables.

Comment: @AndyW I think you might be correct, Andy. After I posted this answer I went searching for a textbook reference, but I haven't yet found it. Thanks for pointing that out.